# How to post to a user's wall while he is offline,renew his token(if expired) via my app. C# Facebook SDK

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, access-token

I know how to use the token after the user successfuly logs in with

```
FacebookLoginDialog(AppId, ExtendedPermissions);
```

but what happens when my app wants to post at this user while he is offline? And how can i renew the token? Is there a way to regognize that a user has allowed the app to post by only his id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request offline_access [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) and then you can post when the user is offline and you want have to worry about refreshing the token.

Comment: so the only thing i have to do is after he accepts my App, to keep in a DB/File/Whatever his ID and Token, and use those to post or what ver i want?. Also do you know a way to regognize if a user has a token for a particular App? Ofcourse i mean that you own this App. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From Facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/):

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission,
>   you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, **without
>   requiring offline_access**.

It seems like there is really no need to have that offline_access permission to post on user's wall while there are offline - there has to be a way to 'refresh' the access token, or use the application's token.